# Default install of XMLHttpRequest in Node Not Working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest

I'm following the instructions to the letter for this package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlhttprequest):

```
import require from 'browserify';
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

But I get this error -

```
file:///dir/src/loadData.js:7
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          ^

TypeError: XMLHttpRequest is not a constructor
    at file:///dir/samples-dashboard/src/loadData.js:7:11
```

What am I missing? My goal is to use the same object in node as in a browser.

Comment: Why are you importing require from browserify instead of using the one built into node?

Comment: When i don't do that, i get a 'ReferenceError: require is not defined'

Comment: Are you running Node in ES6 module mode then? If so, why are you using `import`?

Comment: Heh, sorry, i'm new :) Yes, I'm running it in module mode - I'm really just looking for a cheap and cheerful way to debug locally before i push it all to a website to debug. I thought using node on the command line would do it.

Comment: Given browsers have their own sets of foibles, you'd be better off just testing in a browser in the first place.

Comment: Yeah, I'm suspecting that's right. It just felt like the server side set of tools was so much richer for introspection & debugging.

Comment: Now I'm curious about which tools you would use. Mostly when people ask how to debug Node.js code they are directed to hook it up to the Chrome Debugger.